# Python - trying to remove numerous variables - both existing and non existing

Tags: python, garbage-collection, nonetype, del

When my script ends of execution, I would like to be 100% sure that all variables are removed/that garbage collector will free up my memory.

[del](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#del) allows me to delete any number of variables, providing them separated by comma. For example to delete a,b and c variables, I type:

```
del a,b,c
```

However, if any of those variables does not exists, I receive an exception and it seems that *none* of those variables (a,b,c) are removed.

### Code

So I wrote following code:

```
def tryToRemove(myArrayOfVariablesToRemove):
    # Sample usage: tryToRemove(['a','b'])
    if isinstance(myArrayOfVariablesToRemove, list):
        for i in myArrayOfVariablesToRemove:
            cmd = "del {0}".format(i)
            print(cmd)
            try:
                exec(cmd)
            except NameError:
                pass
    else:
        print("ERROR! Provided argument is *not* a list of variables to remove")
```

### Problem

My code seems to not remove variables.
Typing:

```
a = 3
b = [3,4,5]
tryToRemove(['a','b'])
```

prints on my screen:

```
del a
del b
```

But when I type a, I receive '3', so it seems that variable is not removed.

Comment: Wait, at the end of your script you are trying to manually delete variables? Why?

Comment: Anyway, you are only deleting the names in the local scope. It seems you are trying to accomplish something that is completely unecessary anyway.

Comment: Every var is getting NameError, so all are passed in `except` block.

Comment: You can't delete `global` variable from a function scope without explicit declaration. Add `global {0}` before `del {0}` to fix it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for pointing out my stupid mistake of using local instead of global variables.
Generally speaking my problem is as follows: I wrote some Python methods which calls ESA SNAP API (API written in Java) through snappy module (https://senbox.atlassian.net/wiki/display/SNAP/How+to+use+the+SNAP+API+from+Python).
Once I execute my method for one (input) file, there's no problem.
However, once I execute it multiple times for multiple files I get an exception:

Comment: A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000000055fcfb, pid=9947, tid=140521561863936

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_60-b27) (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.60-b23 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 C  [python+0x15fcfb]
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

Comment: I've tried to fix it (https://github.com/kedziorm/mySNAPscripts/commit/a9cea5d6b0ae94f281356f2e5765674bb9a6c8b8), but I receive the same error again.